# Sum values based on the previous day

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I'm trying to sum sales values from two different dates: the actively filtered day and the one before, so I can subtract one from another and develop a sales growth KPI.
The table looks something like this (with other information in between columns, but the data I want to calculate with is arranged like the table below):

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 11/08/2023 | $850.00 |
| 11/08/2023 | $900.00 |
| 11/09/2023 | $150.00 |
| 11/09/2023 | $250.00 |
| 11/09/2023 | $300.00 |

Gettint the current day's sales sum is easy enough. Inputting the following code gives me the current day's values with no problem:

```
current_day_sales = 

CALCULATE(
    SUM('Database'[Sales])
)
```

The code above returns the correct value. Example, if I filter the day 11/08/2023 it returns $1750.00, and if I filter 11/09/2023 it returns $700.00

The problem is getting the previous day's sales.

I tried using the PREVIOUSDAY function in order to fetch the correct one as a filter, but it is returning blank values. The code I used is the following:

```
last_day_sales = 

CALCULATE(
    SUM('Database'[Sales}),
       PREVIOUSDAY('Database'[Date].[Date])
)
```

I also tried getting the last day on the column using the MAX function and variables, as follows:

```
last_day_sales = 

VAR YestSales = 
   MAX('Database'[Date].[Date]) - 1

RETURN

   CALCULATE(SUM('Database'[Sales]), 'Database'[Date] = YestSales)
```

That also returns blank values. I have all the columns formatted in the correct data formats (dates, decimal numbers, etc), and it doesn't return any errors on the code!

Link to the mock spreadsheet:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/bvpfdsaql7v9urw/Test.xlsx/file

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook?

Comment: Do you have a proper Date dimension? If not, stop and create one. You can do it a zillion different ways. One is something like this:

ADDCOLUMNS(
       CALENDAR(
              MINX('FactTable',[DateColumn]),
              MAXX('FactTable',[DateColumn])
       ),
       "CalendarYear", YEAR([Date]),
       "MonthNumber",MONTH([Date])
)

and then your measure is dead simple:
Prev Day Sales = CALCULATE([Total Sales],PREVIOUSDAY('Date'[Date]))

Comment: I'll edit the workbook to remove any sensitive data and will paste the link on the question, I have the Date column pre-configured on the Excel spreadsheet and also formatted on the PBI archive

Answer (score 0):

Drop `.[Date]`

```
PREVIOUSDAY('Database'[Date])
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?